# Python 3.6 ModuleNotFoundError when trying to access class from different file

Tags: python, django, scrapy

I am having a hard time understanding what I am doing wrong when attempting to import a class to another file, Python_3.6 is the version I am using. I want to mention; I am using the Django Framework to make a web scraping application.

Here is the first class:

```
from scrapy import Item, Field

class Article(Item):
   # define the fields for your item here like:
   # name = scrapy.Field()
   title = Field()
   pass
```

Here is the second class(The error is thrown because of line 2 I know this, but I do not know why?):

```
from scrapy import Spider
from OceanCrawler.WebScraping.wiki.wiki.items import Article

class ArticleSpider(Spider):
    name = "article"
    allowed_domains = ["en.wikipedia.org"]
    start_urls = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page']

def parse(self, response):
    item = Article()
    title = response.xpath('//h1/text()')[0].extract()
    print("TITLE: " + title)
    item['title'] = title
    return item
```

Here is the file structure of my application:[File Struct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/su2nV.png)

When running the command:

```
scrapy crawl article
```

the expected process is a successful web crawl. But instead I receive an error(ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'OceanCrawler') here is the [stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wApDi.png).

I've tried different steps such as using

```
from . import Article
```

The code above results in a syntax error thrown by Pycharm.

**Side Note:**
I know I can fix the issue by including the article class in the same file as the article spider class but I do not want that. I want to keep the items and spiders separated.

Comment: Don't link to pictures of code. Post the actual code here, as text.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Sorry about that its fixed now.

Comment: is OceanCrawler installed?

Comment: @HenryM It is only a file. it holds other files such as migrations, static, etc. My goal is to only import the article class, and by using the path OceanCrawler.WebScraping.wiki.wiki.items I was allowed to use the import article statement with no syntax errors thrown by pycharm, is this not the correct way of importing a class?

Comment: You're trying to import it as a module, which is the error is telling you.  Have a read of this: http://www.daveoncode.com/2017/03/07/how-to-solve-python-modulenotfound-no-module-named-import-error/

Comment: @HenryM I am still a bit confused? I am using the correct path and pycharm also still allows me to import the article class(using intelisense)? Also the same method of including a class is what daveoncode does using the "from" and "import" keywords?